# Cannot convert value of type 'NSArray' to expected argument type '[Any]!'

Tags: swift, objective-c-swift-bridge

I have added an Objective-C category to my Swift 3.0 code. It has a method with header:

```
+(UIBezierPath *)interpolateCGPointsWithHermite:(NSArray *)pointsAsNSValues closed:(BOOL)closed;
```

When I call it from my Swift code:

```
antiAliasing = dict.value(forKey: "antAliasing") as! NSArray
UIBezierPath.interpolateCGPoints(withHermite: antiAliasing, closed: true)
```

I got the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSArray' to expected argument type
>   '[Any]!'

What is the problem with that ?

Comment: `antiAliasing = dict.value(forKey: "antAliasing") as? NSArray ?? [ANY]` This will clear the error but check if r getting the correct results

Comment: U need to unwrap the optional value properly

Comment: From the given parameter label `pointsAsNSValues` I'd try `as! [NSValue]`. And don't use `valueForKey` unless you can explain why you need KVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Replace NSArray with [NSValue], as @vadian suggested
2. Use optional conversion `as?`, since it is more reliable and you won't get a crash if conversion fails.
3. Use subscript instead of `valueForKey` method.

Here is the code:

```
if let antiAliasing = dict["antAliasing"] as? [NSValue] {
    UIBezierPath.interpolateCGPoints(withHermite: antiAliasing, closed: true)
}
```